# How do I use the tsconfig.json "types" field when in a monorepo?

Tags: typescript, yarnpkg, tsconfig, monorepo

## Part 1 - An example of using the "types" field

TypeScript library A provides type definitions **in addition to** its "normal" exports, like this:

```
declare global {
  function someGlobalFunction(): void;
}
```

Library B consumes the type definitions of library A.
Thus, in the tsconfig.json of library B, we put:

```
"types": ["library-a"],
```

- By doing this, using `someGlobalFunction` no longer results in a compiler error.
- Obviously, this requires "library-a" to be listed as a dependency in the package.json of library B.
- Obviously, it also requires that "library-a" is installed and available in the "node_modules" subdirectory.

## Part 2 - A Monorepo

I have a TypeScript monorepo. (It is using NX as the monorepo tool and Yarn as the package manager, but that probably doesn't matter, as this question would apply to any kind of TypeScript monorepo.)

If library A and library B are both in my monorepo, how do I replicate the setup from part 1?

To start with, the monorepo uses the `paths` field in the tsconfig.json file in order for packages to import each other without having to actually install them. This is trivial to do and works well. However, it breaks down if we use the `types` field, as `paths` and `types` do not seem to be programmed to work together. Specifically:

- If I try specifying `"types": ["library-a"]` like before, TypeScript can't find it, saying `library-a` is not found.
- If I try adding a `typeRoots` field to point to the correct "dist" directory, then I can get past that error, but still get a bunch of "not found" errors for all of the individual symbols.
- If I just install `library-a` directly, then everything works, but doing that defeats the whole point of using a monorepo in the first place.

What is the correct way for a package to import the types from another package in a monorepo?

I can provide a minimal reprex repo to illustrate the problem, if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to achieve your desired result using this in `library-b`'s `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["../library-a"],
    "typeRoots": ["../library-a/types"],
    "paths": {
      "library-a": ["../library-a/index.ts"]
    }
  }
}
```

See https://github.com/Maxim-Mazurok/ts-2libs for full reproduction.

In case if I got it wrong - please fork it or provide your own repro.

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time to look into this! Unfortunately, I can't get your solution to work in my setup, so I'll create a sample reprex repository for you shortly.

Comment: See: https://github.com/Zamiell/ts-2libs/blob/change/README.md

Comment: Hi @James, this seems to have did the trick: https://github.com/Maxim-Mazurok/ts-2libs/commit/d572b2c98903605f0d987ad804047a9541d5ee13